# Power cycling SSD drive

Tags: power, usb, repair, sata, ssd

My Crucial M4 SSD stopped working after I had shutdown irresponsive MacBook Pro. I've connected the drive to a USB enclosure but it's not detected by OS (a lamp on enclosure keeps lighting red, whereas it blinks for other drives), however some quiet high frequency noise of changed structure can be heard from the drive (that noise can also be heard when the drive is attached in the MacBook, but noise [seems to be quite common](https://youtube.com/watch?v=AXxoCDVj3Yc) thing for a Crucial SSD, so I wouldn't bother too much about it).

I would like to try "power cycling" method described here:
https://dfarq.homeip.net/fix-dead-ssd/

In the comments under that post and also in few other forums there're anecdotal evidences that the method worked for their SSD drive, like here for another Crucial M4 drive: https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/1n01dc/troubleshooting_strange_fix_to_an_ssd_i_thought/

Moreover, I found a [thread in a web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20171109160800/http://forums.crucial.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/ssd/thread-id/19706/page/1) of Crucial Support Forum where a Crucial employee suggests the same fix:

> Below is the procedure for a power cycle, in most cases your SSD can be returned to normal operating condition by performing the steps listed below:
>
> 1. Find a computer that you can use for approximately 1 hour. We recommend that you try to perform this procedure on a desktop computer
>    because it allows you to only connect the SATA power connection. This
>    will improve the odds of the power cycle being successful. A USB
>    enclosure with an external power source will also work.
>
>    Apple desktop users please follow the same steps as Windows desktop
>    users. If you don't have a desktop, a laptop will work as well. With a
>    laptop you will want to have the drive connected and navigate to the
>    systems BIOS menu. Please refer to your system manufacture’s
>    documentation on how to access the BIOS. Letting the drive sit in the
>    BIOS will improve the odds that the power cycle will work. It is not
>    recommended to use a USB enclosure that is powered via USB. Apple
>    laptop users will want to boot the system to the open firmware.
> 2. Once you have the drive connected and sitting idle for a desktop it is simply powering the computer and waiting. Laptop user will need to
>    be in the BIOS menu, or open firmware as stated above. The computer
>    will need to stay powered on for 20 min, and it is recommended that
>    you don't use the computer during this process.
> 3. Power the computer down and disconnect the drive for 30 seconds.
> 4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 one more time.
> 5. Reconnect the drive normally, and boot the computer to your operating system.
> 6. Update your firmware, if you are not already at the latest on your drive.

So my question is, how can I provide just power without a data, as my USB enclosure board has just one connector combining data and power (see photo)? The first idea was to connect a USB enclosure board with the drive attached to a USB charger, then I thought it might be actually a bad idea, and I rather need a charge-only USB cable. Any other options or thoughts about the method in general?

[image: USB enclosure]

Comment: an SSD should not be making any noises ... there are no moving parts

Comment: also, reddit, "PC master race": um. Not the source of information I'd trust. (really, the technical nonsense the majority there writes is just astonishingly off-mark.)

Comment: anyway, the answer is pretty clear: if you want to try this, get a computer with a power supply that actually has SATA power cables. I wouldn't put any hope in it, though. A "charge-only USB cable" won't help at all. You're still connecting the SATA data pins to the SATA controller on the PCB.

Comment: @jsotola what's making noise is almost certainly the completely undersized power supply on the USB-SATA converter board.

Comment: Anyway, nothing to do with electrical engineering, but usage.

Comment: @jsotola Like I know :) It's very quiet, but it's there, even when the drive is attached inside the MacBook

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited the post adding links to more credible sources (like the official Crucial support forum). Also see my update regarding the noise, it's not coming from USD-SATA board, it's coming form the drive itself no matter where it's connected to. But I don't think that noise thing is something connected to a drive failure, as others reported such noises for working and alive Crucial SSDs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXxoCDVj3Yc

Comment: @Idolon so, with these instructions, it's pretty clear, you need a desktop PC or laptop that will boot without using the drive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yep, it looks like that. Although, the guy from Crucial was suggesting to boot Apple laptop into Open Firmware, but Intel-based Macs don't use Open Firmware, they use EFI and there's no built-in way to enter it, one would have to use something like rEFInd: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). But the thing is, whenever the SSD is connected, my MacBook is stuck with an empty grey screen upon a startup, not reacting to any startup key combinations. I might give another try to use rEFInd bootable usb, or keep the laptop on for 2 cycles of 30 mins, otherwise – desktop PC, FTW!

Comment: as soon as you're in refind, it's already to late and your EFI will have already tried to initialize the SSD. Find a neighbor with a desktop PC.

Comment: Good point! I'll contact an IT colleague, he should have a desktop PC. In the meantime, I'm trying what Jasen suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could put sticky tape over the data contacts

Comment: bit finicky, but might work!

Comment: I used sticky tape and it worked :) Although, SSD didn't start working immediately after power-cycling procedure, but 8 minutes after being powered-on. In a few days I had again the same issue, but that time I just used sticky tape and left SSD connected to power for ~40 mins, and then turn it on normally. And again I had to wait additional 8 minutes for it to start working and be detected by the OS, which makes me wonder, if the only thing I had to do was to actually turn on the MacBook and leave it there for 8 minutes, which I never tried :D

Answer (score 1):

The power cycling didn´t work on my SSD Mushkin Chronos Deluxe 240GB.
I unpluged for 2 years and it worked fine at the last time I need it.
To revive it I connected the power cable, but no data cable, to the SSD.
Turned the PC on and then hit whatever key boots the PC into the BIOS.
Let it sit for 12 hours at the BIOS screen then power down.
I connected the data cable and turned the PC on.
Now the SSD is working like new one.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a simple task. You need nothing more but do a meme trick of inserting usb stick into wall charger: that's exactly what you should do. You just plug that thing into phone charger. It gives the same 5V as your USB ports, but it doesn't have datalines. 5V is 5V, no matter where they come from.

But make sure it's not some Walmart charger, those 50c/10pcs chinese chargers are really noisy. Any charger from more or less known brand will do the trick 100% safely.

MAKE SURE IT'S 5V! You don't want to send 9V or whatever by accident. Output voltage is usually written on the charger itself.

Comment: No, that's not right. The 5V will power the SATA controller on the adapter, and the SSD will see a SATA host being connectted to it

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden my corsair force gt 120gb ssd stopped working and was not detected at all either in computer or in any hdd box so I dig in internet and find this fix power cycyle method and gave it a chance and it worked happily ever after. I used a usb 3.0 hdd box, sticky taped my ssd's data pins(the shorter set is the data pins) and a wall charger. I kept my ssd 2 times 30 minutes powered on. Then connected to computer in a hdd case thru usb. At first it was not detected but after 8-10 mins it was detected and still up. So before ditching your ssd away try this method.